# How do I use a website service to return values into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, api, service

I am trying to use a service that runs on my company website in order to grab some information and use it to populate a field in a form.

I have the service URL https://www.test.co.uk/service/17186914/17186914 where the 2 codes are product SKU's. When this services runs it shows  a JSON file which contains the Product price. I want to be able to grab this price in order to populate a hidden field on a form I am creating.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible making an ajax request. What have you tried so far? If you don't have current code, then you need to do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to `fetch` json data from a url and display it in an input field.

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
  const inputElem = document.querySelector('input');
  inputElem.setAttribute('value', data.title);
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<input />
```

Answer (score 0):

I roughly understood what are you trying to do.

```
      const newVariableThatyouNeed = JSON.parse(yourData);
```

Note that yourData come from the reducer (if you use redux) or the result of your API. And add a new cons with whatever name you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).